# Is running GC.Collect() regularly on a 1GB RAM Raspberry Pi a valid solution for memory problems?

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi, garbage-collection

My app uses more and more memory, that (seems to) gets garbage collected when called explicitly with `GC.Collect()`. When running the application with forced garbage collection, it stays around 60MB usage, when I don't do that I can see the heap grow. I use the "Process Memory" view in Visual Studio 2019 for the measurement.

For a desktop PC this shouldn't be an issue, but my app is a long running web application on a Raspberry Pi with only 1GB of RAM, causing the Pi to lock up after a few days.

My theory now is that the "normal" garbage collector does not run often enough on the Pi to stay stable, and the fix to call `GC.Collect()` regularly should fix that.

Is that correct, or could my application be suffering from some other problem?

Comment: Switching to server mode might help, but the "locking up" is most likely from something else. If the memory is free why shouldn't GC use it?

Comment: @Charlieface when running `free` on the console, I can see the memory is filling up. The locking up is definitely from my application.

Comment: Make it the more aggressive GC setting - start from Workstation Non-concurrent mode.

Answer (score 1):

> For a desktop PC this shouldn't be an issue, but my app is a long running web application on a Raspberry Pi with only 1GB of RAM, causing the Pi to lock up after a few days.

That's not the behavior you get when "running out of RAM", that's what you get when your processor, for example, is overheating.

> My theory now is that the "normal" garbage collector does not run often enough on the Pi to stay stable, and the fix to call GC.Collect() regularly should fix that.

Again, the "stable" part is complete nonsense, but ignoring that, the way the garbage collector works is that it triggers on memory pressure (ie increase in memory consumption per time, as well as percentage of total memory used, higher as it approaches maximum available memory). You triggering it by hand doesn't do anything useful, it would have triggered anyway long before it "ran out of memory".

Comment: Perhaps locking up is the wrong phrasing. The system gets extremely slow after I see the memory filling up with `free`.